# Make golang program restart itself

Tags: go

Im writing a tool and one of its commands allows you to start a new session

How can I make a golang program restart itself? If your solution is OS-Strict im on Linux.

I tried

```
// exec from os/exec
exec.Command(os.Args[0]).Run()
```

but it doesnt work. I get a blank input session which is hard to explain

```
My Program Input:  session new
:(
:(
```

each of the :( represent a blank line where im able to type stuff and hit enter, there are 2 which means i hit enter twice

Im expecting

```
My Program Input: session new
My Program Input:
```

Edit: more accurately, i want to make a subprocess of the same program

Comment: a) what do you mean with "input session"? It seems like your program is doing things that are important to the question but that you're not showing. b) you're not restarting the program. you're trying to start the same binary as a subprocess. waiting for it to complete, while the original binary is still running

Comment: Yeah essentially im trying to make a subprocess. how would i do that?

Comment: Rather than having the program restart itself, it probably is easier to have a shell script with a loop to execute the program again depending on the exit code.

Comment: If you're not asking about restarting the process, then you should edit the question. Currently one comment and one answer assume that you do want to restart.

Comment: For Linux, maybe [try systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77596210/4561887).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate process, like [`radovskyb/gobeat`](https://github.com/radovskyb/gobeat).
Example:

> ```
> sudo gobeat -pid=1234 -cmd="go run sendemail.go"
> ```
>
> 1. Run with `sudo` so `gobeat` will restart the server in the same terminal `tty` that it originated in. (`sudo`)
> 2. Point `gobeat` to the process of the running server that you want gobeat to monitor. (`gobeat -pid=1234`)
> 3. Set the `cmd` flag to run a Go file that will send an email notifying you that the server was restarted. (`-cmd="go run sendemail.go"`)

If you do not want a separate process, then consider implementing a [graceful upgrade](https://blog.cloudflare.com/graceful-upgrades-in-go/)

[image: https://blog.cloudflare.com/content/images/2018/10/upgrade-lifecycle.svg]

You can use the library [`cloudflare/tableflip`](https://github.com/cloudflare/tableflip) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first connect the command to os.Stdin and os.Stdout before running like so:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0])
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
```

This allows the sub-process to write and read to and from stdout/stdin/stderr.

If you also need to pass in all of your command's arguments, use:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], os.Args[1:]...)
```

(after making sure `os.Args[1]` exists)