# Bash script to execute python program if its not running

Tags: python, linux, bash, pid

I have the following bash script to check if my python script miner_nbeats.py is currently running and if not, then re-run because sometimes my python script gets killed due to out of memory error. So I have this bash script below, which works and executed the program at the beginning. However, I noticed that it’s not really re-running the python script after it gets killed.

```
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
while true; do

    if /bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" | grep -v $$ >/dev/null; then
        echo "script running"
    else
        echo "script not running"
        tmux new-session \; send-keys "source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23/directory && python miner_nbeats.py” Enter
    fi
    
    sleep 300
done
```

So I checked the htop program afterwards when `miner_nbeats.py` has been killed but the bash script isn't re-executing the python script since it is failing the first part of the if statement. Moreover, when I check `pgref -f miner_nbeats.py`, it would return me the pid thats associated with the bash script (or the tmux terminal ?)

Hence, I believe that the system is detecting the associated pid from running the bash script.

As an example, when I first run the bash script, it would help me start a new tmux window with the command entered, however, eventually my python script would get killed in the tmux window, and the bash script fails to re-execute the python script.

When I enter the `pgrep -f miner_nbeats.py` it would show a pid of 14826, which is the pid associated with the bash script in htop.

Also the reason I am using the tmux command is because I would like to have the python script running in the background even if my ssh session disconnects from the terminal to the linux server.

I am relatively new to bash scripting and would appreciate any help. Thank you

**-------EDIT-----------**

Thank you for the recommendation on systemd, this is something very new to me and after reading up on systemd, I figured to use something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mining service for nbeats
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=putsncalls23
WorkingDirectory=/home/putsncalls23/directory
ExecStart=/opt/conda/envs/python310/bin/python miner_nbeats.py 
Restart=always
RestartSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Would really appreciate if you could help verify, and it is very helpful for me to learn this new tool since I was stuck in the bash scripting world.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job. Use a systemd service, not a shell script, to keep your services running.

Comment: pipe the pgrep output to grep and use `grep -v` to filter the pgrep entry

Comment: @rioV8 how would i do this ?

Comment: Start your python program this way: `while true; do /path/to/miner_nbeats.py; done`

Comment: @Cyrus Please see my updated post, I have taken this approach to running a while look in a bash script but it doesnt seem to be working at the moment

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow's topicality rules call for _practical_, answerable questions about problems you actually face. I'd argue that ignoring the tools your operating system vendor provides for service management in favor of worse ones is deeply impractical by nature, unless you have a practical reason you can't use those tools.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I updated my solution using systemd and it would be great if you could help verify. I will test it and keep an eye on it. Thanks for suggesting the use of systemd as linux administration and it is my first time using systemd (it is also the first time I have heard of such a process as well)

Comment: to explain why the bash logic was not working: the exit status of pipe command by default is the exit status of the last command here grep -v exit status is success (0) because it always removes the current process from output

Answer (score 3):

Start a systemd service with autorestarting.

It is better to create it system wide in `/etc/systemd/system/miner_nbeats.service` with the following content. The important thing is to set property `Restart=always`.

```
[Unit]
Description=starts my miner_nbeats
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23/test && python miner_nbeats.py'
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then execute as root:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable miner_nbeats
systemctl start miner_nbeats
```

Alternatively, you could start the service ad-hoc with `systemd-run`.

Comment: is this method better than just writing a while loop in a bash file ? Also, would this be executed in tmux ? for example, since im using a cloud server, would the script still execute if i get disconnected ?

Comment: `is this method better than just writing a while loop in a bash file ?` No idea, "better" is subjective without a form of measurement. `would this be executed in tmux ?` No. `would the script still execute if i get disconnected ?` Yes. You may consider reading some introduction to linux administration in particular to systemd.

Comment: @PutsandCalls, why would you need tmux? That's a serious question, because knowing why you want tmux will inform our advice about what to do instead: If you just care about reading logs, a systemd service will let you read logs with `journalctl -u miner_nbeats`, so you don't _need_ tmux. If your program accepts input on stdin, then there's other configuration you can do to wire stdin to a socket or FIFO or other source -- that said, things built to be run as daemons or services can usually be configured to not _need_ stdin control.

Comment: (...and if this is a program you wrote yourself, it'd be good practice to provide a more conventional control mechanism -- via socket or TCP or what-have-you -- should it need one)

Comment: @KamilCuk Might want to make it an explicit `&& exec python miner_nbeats.py` so we don't leave the parent-process copy of bash around. (The `source activate` will also require an explicit working directory so we're run somewhere `activate` actually exists; either the `cd` needs to move earlier, or we need a separate `WorkingDirectory=`... but either way, at this point we need details the OP didn't provide).

Comment: @PutsandCalls, ...while "better" is subjective, this is certainly more in line with what serious professionals do. Look at how the services that come with your operating system are invoked and managed -- none of them use tmux. Good practice involves a chain of custody all the way down from PID 1 -- your init process, if it doesn't directly make sure your process is running itself, making sure that _the thing that starts your process_ is restarted should it fail; that thing making sure whatever _it_ starts is monitored and managed, &c. down to the smallest thing in that chain.

Comment: @PutsandCalls, ...done properly, PID 1 uses the kernel's watchdog driver to cause the whole system to reboot if it fails (and sometimes there's baseboard hardware behind the watchdog to enforce a reboot even if the kernel fails), so there's nowhere in the chain something that can break down without a supervising component noticing and fixing the problem. You don't get that when you're depending on some random shell interpreter to stay alive; a stray signal hits its PID by accident or a transient filesystem error kills it and it's dead, with nothing bringing it back.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually edited my current question instead since I decided to write a bash script which has a while loop as opposed to taking this route. Also, I wanted to use tmux because I would like to keep the python script running in a terminal in case I disconnect from the server. I am currently using google cloud to host my linux server. I currently have a shell script set up in a while loop (which should solve my problem as opposed to using systemd, since I am relatively new to bash/managing linux systems).

Comment: @KamilCuk, Please see my edited question as I would prefer the bash scripting method, if possible

Comment: @PutsandCalls, you don't need tmux to keep your software running after you disconnect -- a systemd service is a child of your init process; it never was connected to a terminal in the first place, so disconnecting terminals doesn't matter. Again, look at how professionals deploy real servers and the machinations you're asking for aren't involved anywhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would also need a tmux terminal because I would like to see the output associated with the miner_nbeats.py file. I believe this would only be possible with tmux if using systemd right ?

Comment: You may consider reading some introduction to linux administration in particular to systemd. System logs on modern systems are available in `journalctl`, I typically do `journalctl -n 100 -u miner_nbeats`.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks, linux administration is very new to me, and I updated my solution which seems to work now in the above post, it'd be great if you could help verify.